# Show hidden div when an introduction div is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my website i have an introduction div for news feed. If an introduction div is clicked then the description should appear using jQuery. But it is not working though the code seem alright.

CSS:

```
.description {
   display: none;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(main);

var main= function() {
    $('.article').click(function(){
        $(this).children('.description').show();    
    });
};
```

Why is it not working please?

Comment: Can you add your to the question. Is `.description` definitely a child of `.article`?

Comment: please share the html as well.

Comment: share the html please

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.article').click(function(){
        $(this).children('.description').show();    
    });

});
```

```css
.description {
   display: none;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article">this is the article
        <div class="description">hi fellow</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try $('.description').show() if that doesn't work try: $('.description').css('display', 'block')

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code snippet:

```
$('.article').click(function(){
    $('.article .description').toggle();    
});
```